# .Net MAUI, Unable to access the WebView element in .XAML file, from the .xaml.cs file

Tags: c#, android, ios, mobile, maui

I am new to .Net MAUI platform. I am trying to load WebView, but I want to pass the URI source dynamically to the webview. I am using VisualStudio 2022 for Mac. I tried this in my MainPage.xaml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="FirstMaui.MainPage">

    <WebView x:Name="webview"> </WebView>

</ContentPage>
```

In my MainPage.xaml.cs file,

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        webview.source = "";
    }
```

Here, the webview is not exposed in this context. How to overcome this?

Comment: What do you mean by "the webview is not exposed in this context"? What exactly is the problem you're dealing with? Do you mean that you cannot access the WebView instance via its `x:Name` in the code-behind?

Comment: BTW, your code won't compile like this, The property name is `Source`, not `source`. Please make sure to post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that actually will compile and demonstrate the issue. You should also assign a proper URL to the `Source` property. Please update your question, explain the problem in more detail and provide a working code example.

Comment: @Julian Thanks for the quick response. Yes, I am unable to access the WebView instance.

Comment: From the doc [.NET MAUI Webview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/webview?view=net-maui-8.0&pivots=devices-android), _A WebView must specify its HeightRequest and WidthRequest properties when contained in a HorizontalStackLayout, StackLayout, or VerticalStackLayout. If you fail to specify these properties, the WebView will not render._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean you can't see the webview then try adding the HeightRequest and WidthRequest.  e.g.

```
 <WebView x:Name="webview"  HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300" > </WebView>
```

Comment: You probably mean `HeightRequest` and `WidthRequest`. This may solve the issue if the problem is that the WebView doesn't get displayed at all, however the question is too vague and doesn't provide sufficient information on this at the moment.

Comment: glad I could help.  Can you mark the answer as correct as I'm trying to build up my reputation points, thank you.

Comment: I still think that both the question and the answer could be improved for future readers. It's not immediately clear from the question that the WebView wasn't displayed at all and the provided code doesn't compile. At the same time, the answer should explain why this solves the issue (apart from fixing the incorrect property names). Just some suggestions for improvement.

Comment: Sometimes the questions aren't that clear but it's worth trying to help someone as they themselves may not be sure how to ask the correct questions, and in this case they're simply missing something.